# A verb for talking about someone who hurt you

Tags: single-word-requests

Consider: A boyfriend cheated on her girlfriend, so she broke up with him. She didn't make a big stink about it, but when she dwells on it, she feels so upset and angry she cannot help saying to herself:

> "I hope somebody will betray him someday."

She does not say these bad wishes to his face, but expresses her anger verbally in her own mind.

**Is there a *verb* which can be used for what she is doing in this situation?**

I thought *to cuss out*, *curse out* or *to swear at*, but I think these phrases would imply she says foul words to his face.

Comment: It sounds to me like you "stew", since you don't seem to be doing anything else.

Comment: It's not clear to me whether you mean bearing a *silent* grudge (saying nothing bad to *anyone* about the person you're resentful towards), or *badmouthing someone behind their back* (telling everyone *except* the object of your vitriol, normally because you're embarrassed or afraid).

Comment: @FumbleFingers consider talking to myself or to a few close friends..but not bad words or lie, just saying some bad wishes :)

Comment: **Backbiting** - [malicious talk about someone who is not present](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/backbiting)

Comment: @FumbleFingers  Can you say " I cried and cursed at him by myself all night"..Again you talk to yourself.

Comment: @Murat: Sure, you can "talk to yourself". But in your specific context it makes a *lot* of difference whether you're talking to yourself or others.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I mean can you curse someone out by talking to yourself. or you can  curse someone out  "only" to his/her face

Comment: Maybe "slander" would be appropriate.

Comment: @Murat: By "curse", do you mean *cause/hope for bad things to happen to someone*, or are you simply venting a general sense of annoyance/grievance?

Comment: @FumbleFingers what do you say for both situations.

Comment: @Murat, I have made some edits to clarify your question. If I have carried your question away from your intentions, you can reverse that edit.

Comment: @ScotM Thank you.This is perfect.Only thing maybe we may add that this question has nothing to do with the word "to gossip"

Comment: I gathered that most of the conversation was internal, from the comments, and that you were not necessarily accusing  the person to others, so it probably won't be necessary to edit the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[***Curse***](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/curse?searchDictCode=all) implies speaking evil in both ways mentioned in the question and comments and can be limited to an internal tirade:

> NOUN
>
> 1.0 A solemn utterance intended to invoke a supernatural power to inflict harm or punishment on
>
> VERB
>
> 1.0 [WITH OBJECT] Invoke or use a curse against:
>
> 2.0 [NO OBJECT] Utter offensive words in anger or annoyance:

If she ***curses him***, rather than cursing **at** him, she diminishes the idea of throwing foul language at him.

*She **cursed** him in hopes that someone would betray him someday.*

---

***[Malign:](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/malign?searchDictCode=all)***

> VERB
>
> [WITH OBJECT]
>
> Speak **about** (someone) in a spitefully critical manner:
>
> **Emphasis** mine.

*She **maligned** him in her heart and mind!*

---

If you intend to wish some actual disaster by your curses you might use the word:

***[Hex](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/hex)***

VERB

> 2. To bring or wish bad luck to:

*She **hexed** him with evil thoughts.*

---

www.oxforddictionaries.com

www.thefreedictionary.com

Comment: _Hex_ goes a step too far, I think—it implies very strongly that you're a gypsy/witch who's putting an actual magical curse on the other person. _Malign_ and _curse_ are good, though of course they don't represent the aspect of ‘biting back’ at someone who hurt you specifically.

Comment: *Hex* seems at the very edge of the semantic field to me to me too. I was surprised to find that definition. I have found that sometimes words on the edge connect with something in the mind of the poster.

Answer (score 4):

You can ***hope they get their comeuppance***, sometimes spelled ***come-uppance***. 
It may not entirely provide what you need because there is no inference contained in the word itself that it is an unspoken hope of he/she who seeks vengeance.

It means *getting what they deserve*. It was coined in the mid-19th century. I believe it may have been used by Dickens, but no reference of his is quoted in the OED entry, which I reproduce below in its entirety.

orig. English and U.S. dial., now gen. in the U.S., less common elsewhere.
Thesaurus »
Categories »

Enough to serve one (by way of retaliation or check); one's deserts.

1859   Harper's Mag. Jan. 277/1   Dennis once got his ‘come-up-ance’.

1880   M. A. Courtney Gloss. Words W. Cornwall in Gloss. Cornwall 14/1   Come-upping, a flogging. ‘I'll gi' 'ee a sound come-upping.’

1884   W. D. Howells Rise Silas Lapham viii. 366   Rogers is a rascal... But I guess he'll find he's got his come-uppance.

1897   E. Higginson Tales Puget Sound 155,   I can give him his come-up-'ans if he goes to foolin' around.

1897   W. D. Howells Landlord Lion's Head xxi. 153   Well, I did get my come-uppings that time.

1923   ‘B. M. Bower’ Parowan Bonanza vi. 70   ‘An' that's where he got 'is come-uppance,’ he gloated.

1943   D. W. Brogan Eng. People i. 21   The roles of teacher and taught were suddenly reversed, to the delight of a world that saw the English at last get their come-uppance.

1957   G. B. Stern Seventy Times Seven 15   She's bound to get her come-uppance one day.

1959   Cambr. Rev. 2 May 461/2   When they actually appoint [at Cambridge] a sociologist they will get their comeuppance.

1963   Ann. Reg. 1962 40   Fleet Street, accustomed to pour scorn on the inefficiencies of other industries, had its ‘comeuppance’ with the report of the Shawcross Commission.

Answer (score 2):

One oft-used phrase is ***wish ill upon***: the girl is *wishing ill* upon her ex-boyfriend. You often hear this phrase used in conjunction with people who are caught up in heat-of-the-moment anger.

You can find the phrase in books:

> Almost always, those who hate wish ill upon the person at whom they are angry.
> <sub>(Source: *Anger: Handling a Powerful Emotion in a Healthy Way*, by Gary D Chapman, 2008.)</sub>

I found this tongue-in-cheek [tweet](https://twitter.com/sarahmaclean/status/448478856996196352) as another example:

> There are days when I wish ill upon the person who invented “Reply All.” Today might be one of them.

And one [blogger](http://valuesandcapitalism.com/what-s-wrong-with-social-justice/) wrote:

> We all have the impulse to wish ill upon our neighbors as a way of making us feel better about ourselves. It is destructive, but difficult to overcome.

Those usages seem to align pretty closely with what you are asking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can **hope they get what's coming to them** to mean you hope they get what you feel they deserve, as in "I hope she gets what's coming to her."

Answer (score 0):

*gossip* probably applies, as well. It's pretty much the same thing, whatever you say behind someone's back usually spreads like wildfire anyway.

Comment: @Murat hoping, wishing, praying, stewing, thinking bad thoughts, ... worrying, fretting, festering... what ever you do within yourself.